# QAbstractItemView::setSelectionModel() failed: Trying to set a selection model, which works on a different model than the view

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to assign a Selection Model to my QTableWidget

```
    def initPlotTW(self):
        plotTWHeaderLabels = ['Select','Plot name','Marker','Color','Linestyle','Linewidth','Axis']
        plotTW = self.plotTW
        plotTW.setColumnCount(len(plotTWHeaderLabels))
        plotTW.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(plotTWHeaderLabels)
        plotTW.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setSelectionModel()
        plotTW.itemSelectionChanged.connect(lambda:self.test())
    

    def setSelectionModel(self):
        plotTWModel = QtCore.QItemSelectionModel()
        self.plotTW.setSelectionModel(plotTWModel)
```

But  this print out the error:

```
QAbstractItemView::setSelectionModel() failed: Trying to set a selection model, which works on a different model than the view.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have to set the target model for the selection model. `plotTWModel = QtCore.QItemSelectionModel(self.plotTW.model())`. That said, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve with that, since it won't change anything.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the answer, I was supposed to subclass it but thanks for the answer either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is actually clear: the selection model *must* be the same that is used on the view.

Which is quite obvious: since the selection model uses the model of the view, that selection model has to be *set* on that same model. Setting the model on the view is ***not*** sufficient, and this is also because, as the documentation for [`setModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setModel) explains:

> This function will create and set a new selection model, replacing any model that was previously set with setSelectionModel().

Most importantly, a selection model can be shared between *multiple* item views, so it cannot (nor should) "automatically inherit" the source model of the view: the source model must be explicitly set; so, creating a QItemSelectionModel alone is insufficient: it has no reference to the model for the view.

Since you're probably using a subclass, the solution is to call the base implementation with the model as its first argument, or explicitly call [`setModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#setModel):

```
class MyCustomSelectionModel(QItemSelectionModel):
    def __init__(self, model=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(model, parent)

# and, then:

    plotTWModel = MyCustomSelectionModel(self.plotTW.model())

# or, alternatively:

    plotTWModel = MyCustomSelectionModel()
    # ...
    plotTWModel.setModel(self.plotTW.model())

# finally:

    self.plotTW.setSelectionModel(plotTWModel)
```

In both cases, the model of the view ***must*** be set.